# Django - Prefill admin creation form with inline forms

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a form in Django admin, that, when you create a new entry, will take the latest entry, and fill the new entry with that data.
E.g. (Book and Author are just examples)

```
class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.Autofield(primary_key=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=200)


class Author(models.Model):
    id = models.Autofield(primary_key=True)
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=200)
```

I then added this to the admin page:

```
class BookInline(StackedInline):
    model = Book
    extra = 0

class AuthorAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BookInline]

admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)
```

Now when I create a new Author, I want the form to be filled in with the last created author and his books
So if said author had 5 books, it would now fill this form with the name of that author, and also add the 5 books.

I was able to fill the author form by adding this to the AuthorAdmin class:

```
def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
    return model_to_dict(Author.objects.all().get())#Temp
```

But the books are not filled this way. Is it somehow possible, to pass the books into the inline forms?

(Running Django 3.2 and Python 3.9)